# turn flashlight on iphone with phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

I want to know if there is a javascript function through phonegap where I can activate the iphone's camera light.

Does this need to be a .h .m type deal or can it be done through a javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the phonegap [Torch Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Torch) for iOS.